# Jenkins conditional step for string contains

Tags: jenkins, deployment, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to do a conditional step on Jenkins to see if the String Parameter contains a certain word.

I have a string for `PLATFORM`. The values in it can be `Windows, Mac, Linux`

I want to run a certain step if the value of the parameter contains Linux.

How can I do that? I downloaded the Jenkins plugin for conditional step but it doesn't have a contains clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [when](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) directive of Jenkins to achieve the conditional steps.

**Example:**

```yaml
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage ('Windows RUN') {
            when {
                expression { params.PLATFORM == 'Windows' }
            }
            steps {
                echo "Hello, Windows"
            }
        }
        
        stage ('Mac RUN') {
            when {
                expression { params.PLATFORM == 'Mac' }
            }
            steps {
                echo "Hello, Mac"
            }
        }
        
        stage ('Linux RUN') {
            when {
                expression { params.PLATFORM == 'Linux' }
            }
            steps {
                echo "Hello, Linux"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a Jenkinsfile... using Build steps such as Execute Windows Batch command